# Generate Random String is very slow

Tags: vb.net, string, text, random, numbers

I like to generate a random string in vb.net.
I already wrote a function which does the job:

[image]

But this way of generating random strings is very slow and for ~5 Textboxes it takes nearly a second to generate the strings. 
How can I speed up my piece of code?

Every help is appreciated :)

Comment: How long are the strings being generated?

Comment: The random Strings are only 20 digits long.

Comment: This should not be slow. There must be some other bottlenecks. Try a console application and paste this code into that. Also take two variables to note  down the time in milliseconds both before and after your code.then run to check how much time this piece of code is taking.

Comment: I agree, it should not be slow.

Comment: So I posted some test code as an answer.

Comment: EDIT: If you ever want the function to generate a `1` then change `rnd.Next(1 , 62)` to `rnd.Next(0 , 62)` as the `minValue` is inclusive and the `maxValue` is **exclusive**. Note: Arrays in `vb.net` are zero-based.

Comment: I agree with Bjorn.  Also, you do not need to hard code the maxval(62), just use CharSet.Length.  If you add/remove characters to the set you don't need to change anything else.

Answer (score 1):

So I tested it.  Less than a second to generate 100, 200 character strings.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim stpw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
    For x As Integer = 1 To 100
        TextBox1.Text = RandomString(200)
        TextBox1.Refresh()
    Next
    stpw.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine(stpw.Elapsed)
End Sub

Dim prng As New Random
Private Function RandomString(desiredLength As Integer) As String
    Dim CharSet As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    Dim rv As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For ct As Integer = 1 To desiredLength
        rv.Append(CharSet(prng.Next(0, CharSet.Length)))
    Next
    Return rv.ToString
End Function
```

edit: New test, less than a ms., even when the button is pressed as fast as possible.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim stpw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
    TextBox1.Text = RandomString(200)
    TextBox2.Text = RandomString(200)
    TextBox3.Text = RandomString(200)
    stpw.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine(stpw.Elapsed)
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, nice! But when I assign this random function to my textboxtext like this: http://puu.sh/a9pqb/b797cc6e5f.png I still can not really generate the numbers that fast. When I am clicking the button very fast it is still not generating the numbers every time :/

Comment: I added your test to this.  My guess is that you have other events hooked up to the textboxes.

Comment: Nope, there are no other events.

Comment: My test, using more characters, runs in under a ms.  Your test doesn't so it has to be something else.  I think the RandomString method is not the problem.  FWIW - I also tested using .ElementAt, which is not needed, and the results where the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

```
Dim Randomizer As New Random

' Get Random String
' // By Elektro
'
' Usage Examples :
' MsgBox(GetRandomString("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 10))
' MsgBox(GetRandomString("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 10, True))
'
''' <summary>
''' Gets a random string.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="CharacterSet">Indicates the characters to randomize.</param>
''' <param name="StringLength">Indicates the resulting string length.</param>
''' <param name="RandomizeCase">If set to <c>true</c>, lower-case and upper-case are randomized.</param>
''' <returns>System.String.</returns>
''' <exception cref="System.Exception">
''' CharacterSet is empty.
''' or
''' String-Length must be greater than 0.
''' </exception>
Private Function GetRandomString(ByVal CharacterSet As Char(),
                                 ByVal StringLength As Integer,
                                 Optional ByVal RandomizeCase As Boolean = False) As String

    Select Case CharacterSet.Count

        Case Is = 0
            Throw New Exception("CharacterSet is empty.")

        Case Is = 1
            Return New String(CharacterSet.First, Math.Abs(StringLength))

        Case Else

            Select Case StringLength

                Case Is < 1
                    Throw New Exception("String-Length must be greater than 0.")

                Case Else

                    Dim CharSetLength As Integer = CharacterSet.Length
                    Dim CharSB As New System.Text.StringBuilder

                    Do Until CharSB.Length = StringLength

                        If Not RandomizeCase Then
                            CharSB.Append(CharacterSet(Randomizer.Next(0, CharSetLength)))

                        Else

                            Select Case Randomizer.Next(0, 2)

                                Case 0 ' Lower-Case
                                    CharSB.Append(Char.ToLower(CharacterSet(Randomizer.Next(0, CharSetLength))))

                                Case 1 ' Upper-Case
                                    CharSB.Append(Char.ToUpper(CharacterSet(Randomizer.Next(0, CharSetLength))))

                            End Select

                        End If '/ Not RandomizeCase

                    Loop '/ CharSB.Length = StringLength

                    Return CharSB.ToString

            End Select '/ StringLength

    End Select '/  CharacterSet.Count

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VB and it's syntax but here's some c# code which you might be able to convert.  I'm not sure how much faster this would be.

```
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    var randomString = new string(
        Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 20)
                  .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                  .ToArray());
    return randomString ;
```

Comment: LINQ queries are not fast

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
Dim chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Dim random = New Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())
Dim randomString = New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 20).[Select](Function(s) s(random.[Next](s.Length))).ToArray())
Return randomString
```

Comment: I never understand why people feel the need to seed the random number generator.

Comment: pseudorandom you mean :)

Comment: LINQ queries are not fast

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Random.NextBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method as follows:

```
Dim rnd As New System.Random

Private Function NewRandomString(ByVal length As Integer) As String
    If length <= 0 Then Return ""
    Dim CharSet As String = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    Dim GenRandomStr As New StringBuilder
    Dim RandomBytes(length - 1) As Byte
    rnd.NextBytes(RandomBytes)

    For i As Integer = 0 To length - 1
        GenRandomStr.Append(CharSet(RandomBytes(i) Mod CharSet.Length))
    Next

    Return GenRandomStr.ToString
End Function
```

to compare the speed of this function, use the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Stopwatch As New Stopwatch
    Stopwatch.Start()

    For i As Integer = 1 To 100000
        RandomString(200)
    Next

    Stopwatch.Stop()
    MsgBox("Original time [" & Stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString() & "]")

    Stopwatch.Reset()
    Stopwatch.Start()

    For i As Integer = 1 To 100000
        NewRandomString(200)
    Next

    Stopwatch.Stop()
    MsgBox("New time [" & Stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString() & "]")
End Sub
```

for 100000 iterations (on an i7 4770k), I get times around these:

```
Original time [00:00:00.5434907]
     New time [00:00:00.3569711]
```

34% faster